# How can I add a variable into an Excel formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, offset

Under the `COUNTIF` formula, I would like to look at the next column in response sheet after I move 2 rows down (`ActiveCell.Offset`). How should I go about that?
Can someone explain why when I want to look at column C, the coding is C3, while column D is C4?

```
Sub x()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To 100    
        ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1).Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF('Responses'!C4,data!R8C)"
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF('Responses'!Ci,data!R8C)"
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:E1"), Type:= _
            xlFillDefault
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:E1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean, but I rewrite that make your code more readable. Might be it will help you solve the matter. Can you explain more detail about the requirement?

```
Sub x()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 3 To 100
        ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIF(Responses!R" & i & "C, data!R8C)"
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:E1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: oh what i am trying to do is, i would like to count the number of 'agree', strongly agree', etc responses for the questions stored in a different worksheet. there's quite a few questions. so i would it to run for me in the case where after i calculate the response for the first qn, it will move to the next column.

Comment: You mean current sheet contains questions in a range A1:E1, "Response" sheet contains user's response corresponding to the question, store in range A3:E100. And you wanna count number of response for each question as the condition of sheet "data" Range C8, put the result in current sheet's range A3:E3? Isn't that?